# Unreal Engine YouTube video play inside scene/game

Tags: youtube, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

its is very easy to play videos saved in the Unreal Engine from Content files.

mediaSource > mediaPlayer > mediaPlayerTexture
applying mediaPlayerTexture to Plane in scene/level.

Blueprint-> eventBeginPlay > openSource

**But I want to play videos from link(youtube).**

I got few option like "Electra Media Player" / "Browser Plugin".

can any tell me how to add YouTube Videos in the Unreal Engine

Answer (score 0):

check web browser widget at the UMG.
you need to activate Web Browser Plugin first.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for this, I think there are 2 ways you can achieve this

1. Web browser plugin, enable it from Plugin, and use Canvas to show the web interface.
2. Using Media Player + StreamMediaSource, you can use the OpenURL node. Give the URL of the video you want to play and the Media Player in target inputs.